# Route Model Binding on different database

Tags: laravel

I have multiple databases and as a model considers default connection when invoked from a route model binding, it says table not found. How can i bind the model in a resource controller edit/update method as a part of Route Model binding to consider the current connection and not the default connection?
PS -  I cannot declare $connection on the model because, i won't know which database it will be accessing at a said moment.

Comment: Use `Route::bind(function ($id) { /* custom code */ });` to specify custom logic instead of automatic binding since you seem to have logic that can't be auto-bound.

Comment: Ok, i did this, and it properly connects and returns the data. this is what i used- 
    Route::bind('posts', function ($value) {
        $dbName = session('dbName');
        \Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database',$dbName);
        \DB::setDefaultConnection('tenant');

       return Posts::find($value);
    });

Now, what i feel is the issue here is, i have many models, so binding each one of them, wherever i feel resourcecontrollers are to be made for Route Model binding will be a heavy task. Is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a route middleware to set the database connection for particular routes. To do this you will need to set up your connections in your database config, and then add the middleware.

I use a similar setup in a multi-tenant application to manage system vs tenant database connections. Database config:

```
'connections' => [

   'system' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'lms'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'lms'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'lms'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'tenant' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => '',
        'username' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
],
```

The middleware in my example enforced the use of a database defined as tenant.

```
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class EnforceTenancy
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        Config::set('database.default', 'tenant');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

You can then register the middleware in the kernel.php $routeMiddleware array

```
'tenancy.enforce' => \App\Http\Middleware\EnforceTenancy::class,
```

and then apply the middleware in your route file for any route that requires the second db.

Comment: a side note, the tenant connection details are blank, as they are set at runtime depending on the signed in tenant, you can set your db details as required.

Comment: I have the exact configuration, I have emptied the tenant connection, and on every request i have to set database in my custom checksession middleware, and i have also put in the kernel and used in the Route group. All things works perfectly. Only thing that breaks is while Rote Model Binding , if i try something like public function update(User $user),i get an error saying centraldb.user doesn't exist. That means, it always takes the default connection as mentioned in the Documentation. I tried to dd($request) in my middleware,but it is not passing through, without Model binding it works tho.

Comment: Also, please have a look above to my solution, i have a workaround, but it needs some inputs.